# Install database datatypes using MDG file or add-in?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I was able to define a custom programming language in Enterprise Architect with custom data types by navigating to `Project > Settings > Code Engineering Datatypes...`. When I create a MDG file, I have the option to include the programming language definition, and as far as I can tell, this is working - at least, in a new project that uses the MDG file, I can see the programming language.

Now I would like to have the same behavior for DBMS and database datatypes defined through `Project > Settings > Database Datatypes...`. From my tests, I get the impression that these types are not automatically included in the MDG file, and I haven't found a trivial way to include them. Is there a way to add the database datatypes to the MDG file as well? If not, is there a way to achieve the same result through the automation interface, e. g. by writing an add-in that creates the DBMS and the associated datatypes?

Comment: Just speculating, but Sparx is cooking different soups in their EA. Not unlikely that the DB cook has not talked to that responsible for code engineering. You should cross post on Sparx' forum. This kind of question is best answered by one of the Sparxians,

Answer (score 2):

Going the MDG Technology way, the answer appears to be no. It's possible to trick EA (11) into exporting DB types in an MDG Technology, but even if they're in there, they will be ignored in projects that use the MDG Technology.

DB types and code engineering (or, sometimes, "programming language") datatypes are both stored in EA's t_datatypes table. The same product name can be used for both a programming language and a DB engine.

It looks like the MDG Technology Wizard scans this table looking for rows with "Code" in the Type column during the setup (Code Modules wizard page), but when the time comes to write the actual datatypes into the output file, it retrieves all rows with the specified ProductName.

This means that if you create a DB product and populate it with a set of datatypes, and then create a programming language product with the same name but just a single dummy datatype, your DB types will be included in the MDG Technology XML file along with the dummy type.

However, it appears that while the regular properties dialog (for classes etc) checks the loaded MDG Technologies in addition to the t_datatypes table in order to populate the Language drop-down list, the specialized properties dialog for database tables does not check the MDG Technologies when populating the corresponding Database drop-down. So even though the datatypes are in the file, you can't use them.

Going the Add-In route, the answer is yes.

Have your Add-In respond to the EA_FileOpen event and check the Repository.Datatypes collection to see if your DB types are installed and if not, add them.

You don't actually need to write an Add-In if you don't want, you can write an in-EA script. The only thing an Add-In can do that scripts can't is respond to events (which is why those are listed in the Add-In Model section of the help file). So with a script you would have to trigger the function manually.

There is also an API to manage project's reference data of which code / DB datatypes is one category, but it only gives you control of some of the categories (eg requirement types and constraint types), and the datatype category is not one of them.